# Sorting List which has object that contains two string members that contains numbers

Tags: c#, linq

I want to know the best solution for this

my case here is that i am taking values from Excel sheet and pushing them to database field, sometimes that field might contain some strings (thats why I cant make my object members `int` / `double`)

In my class below size is the variable responsible for showing size of files in bytes

```
public class dataNameValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to sort the list by file Size something like

```
List<dataNameValue> mylist = new List<dataNameValue>();
mylist = mylist.OrderByDescending(i => i.Size).ToList();
```

The problem is that if i sorted it without converting it to "int/double" first -- its not giving right results

[image]

Note: all the data i get from database to that list is numbers

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Please give sample of possible `Size` variable values. Also how do you want to sort values which are not numbers?

Comment: How should the "int/double" values be sorted with the text? Is all text greater or less than a number?

Comment: i updated the question :) i need to convert that field to int/double and sort it first before doing that linq line

Comment: I would suggest that you save Size as the correct type in the database rather than try to massage the data. Can you give us an example of the string values that is preventing you from saving the Size as an int?

Comment: @user65439 sometimes the excel sheet might have some text that client wants it to be pushed to database

Comment: You really should work with two separate lists. One that has proper numeric values and the other with the text values.

Comment: @Lemo your Size is always in GB or it can be any other unit? Does it always have percentage part?

Comment: @Lemo see solution with custom object for size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sizes in form of *value units (percentage)* then I would go with Size class instead of string:

```
public class Size
{
    public static Size Parse(string s)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<value>\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*(?<units>\w+)\s*.*");
        var match = regex.Match(s);
        if (!match.Success)
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown size format");

        return new Size {
            Value = Double.Parse(match.Groups["value"].Value),
            Units = GetSizeUnits(match.Groups["units"].Value)
        };
    }

    private static SizeUnit GetSizeUnits(string units)
    {
        switch (units.ToUpper())
        {      
            // sorry don't know how you define bytes in your system
            case "KB": return SizeUnit.Kilobyte;
            case "MB": return SizeUnit.Megabyte;
            case "GB": return SizeUnit.Gigabyte;
            case "TB": return SizeUnit.Terabyte;
            default: throw new ArgumentException("Unknown size units");
        }
    }

    public double Value { get; private set; }
    public SizeUnit Units { get; private set; }
    public double ValueInBytes
    {
        get { return Math.Pow(1024, (int)Units) * Value; }
    }
}
```

It can simply parse such strings as `"5.66 GB (7.75%)"` into size object with appropriate units and calculate value in bytes. E.g.

```
var size = Size.Parse("240.5 MB (0.4%)");
```

[image]

Units is simple enum

```
public enum SizeUnit
{
    Byte,
    Kilobyte,
    Megabyte,
    Gigabyte,
    Terabyte
}
```

With this type instead of string, you can sort list of data very easily

```
mylist = mylist.OrderByDescending(d => d.Size.ValueInBytes).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Example of a user define Parse mehod to place the ill formatted objects at the end of the list.

If you want to sort by an integer (the Size) then you *must* first convert the string size to an integer, and then sort as you did.

You could:
1) Ignore and remove object that cannot provide a correct Size
2) If you cant remove them, you can place the objects with an incorrect Size member at the end (or at the begining) of the list.

```
// return MaxValue if int cannot be parsed: this will put the garbage strings t the end of the list
int Parse(string s)
{
 int result;
 if(!int.TryParse(s, out result))
   return int.MaxValue;
 return result;
 }

mylist = mylist.OrderByDescending(i => Parse(i.Size)).ToList();
```

Comment: OP stated, that size might contain *some* strings which cannot be converted to int/double

Comment: -1 This will not work. He has text interspersed with numeric values.

Comment: i retrieve all fields that contains numbers only in that list

Comment: I would do `.OrderByDescending(i => Parse(i.Size)).ThenBy(i => i.Size).ToList()` so it sorts the unparseable items too at the end alphabetically.

Comment: Removed -1. But I don't know if this solves the problem or not, since we're still waiting for clarification from the OP about how he wants to sort these things. I suspect that the real solution is to separate the data into two sets early and then not have these problems. We just have to get there step-by-step.

Comment: @karim for some reason it sorts fine except for the 2 digits http://screencast.com/t/4bN4YjXxV is there a way to discuss this with you in a chat room or something ?

Answer (score 0):

create this class

```
public class dataNameValueComparer : IComparer<dataNameValue>
{
    public int Compare(dataNameValue x, dataNameValue y)
    {
        //Here process your comparation
        //return  <0 if x<y 
        // 0 if x=y 
        // >0 if x>y
        //This sample return the default string compration
        return string.Compare(x.Size, y.Size);
    }
}
```

Then use this for sorting

```
mylist = mylist.OrderByDescending(i => i,new dataNameValueComparer() ).ToList();
```

You can create various classes for comparing as need.
Like

```
public class SizeComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            //Here process your comparation
            //return  <0 if x<y 
            // 0 if x=y 
            // >0 if x>y
            //This sample return the default string compration
            return string.Compare(x, y);
        }
    }
```

And using your original call adding the comparer parameter

```
   mylist = mylist.OrderByDescending(i => i.Size,new SizeComparer() ).ToList();
```

In the comparator you can made any conversion of Size